# Running a special discount, but the price not reflecting on cart page

Tags: product, cart, discount, pricing

So i updated the pricing for the discount campaign. However, for the people who have added the products added in the cart can see the old pricing and add the coupon code. please help[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please share your cart price rule or which conditions apply for discount?